# Getting an error when trying calling Json.deserialize on a Quote Object

Tags: apex

I am trying to use Json.deserialize to a Quote Object and I am getting this error -  Invalid field class for SObject Quote.

This is my code -

```
Quote quote;
    try {
        quote = (Quote)Json.deserialize(quoteString, Quote.class);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: apex is case insensitive, consider using different variable names. Or use Schema.Quote.class instead of Quote.class

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the name `quote` for your instance, you need to avoid naming conflicts. This approach would work:

```
quote = (Schema.Quote)Json.deserialize(quoteString, Schema.Quote.class);
```

As would this one:

```
quote = (Schema.Quote)Json.deserialize(quoteString, Type.forName('Quote'));
```